# Trying to implement a WebDriverActionListener Class

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, event-listener

So I've created a `WebDriverActionListener` class. I register with my driver instance however the `OnElementClicking` does not fire.

I'm trying to register with my page constructer like so:

```
public Page(IWebDriver driver): base(driver)
{
     this.driver = new WebDriverActionListener(driver);
     PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
}
```

Here is my eventlistner class

```
public class WebDriverActionListener : EventFiringWebDriver 
{
    #region Object Declarations

    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    #endregion

    public WebDriverActionListener(IWebDriver parentDriver) : base(parentDriver)
    {
        driver = parentDriver;
    }
    protected override void OnElementClicking(WebElementEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementClicking(e);

        if (IsMobile()) //method in another class
        {
            e.Element.Move(driver); //method in another class
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone suggest why this is, I do not to do register my listener class like so `driverExtensions = new WebDriverExtensions(this.driver);` as it would require quite a lot of code change.

Thanks